# Can't use a class that is defined in another hpp file

Tags: c++, class, include

I'm having a little problem trying to use my "gameAux" class in "userAux.hpp" file I made.

Here are the two hpp files I made.

I marked the place where I get an error.

userAux.hpp:

```
#include "gameAux.hpp"


class userAux{
   int gameId;
   int userId;
   int rate;
   gameAux aGame; <---error: ‘gameAux’ does not name a type
};
```

gameAux.hpp:

```
#include "userAux.hpp"

class gameAux{
  int gameId;
  userAux aUser; <--- OK
};
```

I'll be very happy if someone could point out what's the problem :)

Comment: This has been answered many times. You have a cyclic dependency which you must resolve.

Comment: so how can I use each type inside other?

Comment: @user3023388 Use pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that both of your classes depend on each other. When the compiler goes to see how much space it needs to reserve for `gameAux` objects, it says 'ok, I need an int and a userAux to fit in there'. So the next question is, how much space does it need for ints and userAux objects?

Then when it tries to figure out how much space it needs for a userAux object, it says 'ok, three ints and a gameAux object'... and there's the problem. It's going to keep going back and forth between those two files, trying to figure out how much space it needs for each thing, and never be able to figure it out.

To solve this, you need to make one of your classes depend on a **reference** or **pointer** to the other class. Since references and pointers always take up the same amount of space on a given system, the compiler will be able to allocate space for a userAux if it sees this:

```
class gameAux;

class userAux{
   int gameId;
   int userId;
   int rate;
   gameAux &aGame; // or gameAux *aGame; // <---error: ‘gameAux’ does not name a type
};
```

and then it will have a fine time allocating space for both of the objects, no problems ^^

EDIT: Also, you won't need to `#include` the header file for gameAux any more at the top of userAux.hpp - just forward-declare gameAux like so at the top of the file: `class gameAux`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have one class include an instance of another class, and have that other class include an instance of the first class. That's an infinite recursion and obviously cannot work.

The answer is to use pointers and forward declarations.

```
class gameAux; // forward declaration

class userAux{
   int gameId;
   int userId;
   int rate;
   gameAux* aGame;
};

class gameAux{
  int gameId;
  userAux* aUser;
};
```

When two classes depend on each other like this I would be tempted to place them both in the same header file. However if you want separate header files then you could forward declare each class in the other classes header file. That way neither header file needs to include the other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the entire class definition.  You can avoid a circular dependency by just forward declaring, and using a pointer:

```
#include "gameAux.hpp"

class gameAux;     // forward declaration

class userAux{
   int gameId;
   int userId;
   int rate;
   gameAux *aGame;
};
```

and vice versa in the other file.  Then `#include` the appropriate hpp header in the implementation source file for each class.

Comment: This won't work unless the gameAux is declared as a reference or a pointer ^^